# How to create ASP.Net Core Cookie on first request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

We've ported a large web application to .Net 6. We have everything working, but we're working on cleaning up the code.

In .Net Framework, we created a session cookie on the first request in the session using the IsNewSession method on HttpSessionState in a HttpModule.

In .Net 6, we need to store a cookie on the first request to achieve the same functionality. We have managed to create a cookie that works in the same way, but we haven't found the correct place to put it. For now we have put it in a DynamicRoutingValueTransformer.

Where and how can we create a cookie in the first request in a visit in the correct way in .Net 6?

Comment: Could please explain what did you mean by `" but our method doesn't feel right."`  what's  not working as expected? What are you trying to implement?

Comment: Now we're creating the cookie in DynamicRoutingValueTransformer. It works, but this is clearly the wrong place. It was done more as a test than a full implementation. What we're wondering is where such code should reside in .Net 6?

Comment: Could please upate the question with what you have implemented so far and looking forward the way in `.Net 6` so that it would be easier to understand.